# Why does a directory exist and not exist on a web server simultaneously?

Tags: http

While I'm sure the title could be improved for clarity, my meaning is thus:

When fetching a URL for a file download at `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/file.zip`, the response code is `200`, yet attempting to access `http://example.com/dir1`, or `http://example.com/dir1/dir2`, elicits a `404` response code.

Why is this?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs don't necessarily correspond to actual directories on the server.  Ultimately the path component of a URL is just a name; the server can translate that name to whatever it wants on the back end.

In this case it seems likely that `/dir1/dir2/` *is* a directory on the server, but even so that doesn't mean anything.  The server knows about a resource named `/dir1/dir2/file.zip`, but doesn't know anything about a resource named `/dir1`.